# Reducing Maven Dependencies

Tags: maven, osgi, aem

I am using Maven to build my project. There are lot of dependencies which are in provided and runtime scope. The build size is large and I want to remove the unwanted dependencies. So is there any way in which I can check which dependencies are unwanted.

Comment: First would be to use: `mvn dependency:analyze` and step by step remove dependencies which you might not need.

Comment: If you are working with AEM 6.X I would just use the uber-jar dependency as a start and re-add the ones that are missing, one by one.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to minimize dependencies to the ones you really need is to not embed that dependencies. If you simply use the maven-bundle-plugin on your code it will create Import-Package statements for the code you really need. This might even give you a good hint on what dependencies you might be able to exclude for embedding.

In general in OSGi the goal should be to not have that many dependencies in the first place. If you use libraries with extensive dependencies then your should question the quality of these.